# Keep android service alive using bindService

Tags: android

I start service using bindService method.

But when I click on back button on android emulator  my service is destroyed.

How can I keep service live in whole application (I must use bindService for communitacion with activities)?

Thanks

**Update**
Here is error log

```
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905): Activity com.flax.trainer.RunOnly has leaked ServiceConnection com.flax.trainer.RunOnly$1@43e3fb40 that was originally bound here
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.flax.trainer.RunOnly has leaked ServiceConnection com.flax.trainer.RunOnly$1@43e3fb40 that was originally bound here
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:1121)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getServiceDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:1016)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:863)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at com.flax.trainer.RunOnly.butonStartClickHandler(RunOnly.java:85)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-10 18:28:18.352: ERROR/ActivityThread(905):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Ok, so you want to run this service at all times, even when the app is closed?

Comment: No, when I press back button I back to my main activity. I don't close my application, just back to main activity.Thanks

Comment: I bind to the service in all my activities' onStart() method, then unbind in onStop(). onStart() of the next activity is called before onStop() of the last one.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag than your service will be destroyed when activity is closed.
You should use `startService()` before `bindService()` to prevent this